# Seemingly simple query throws error

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables for a lab I'm working on. Table 1 is a list of job titles, with a description, title, and status field, along with a index value that I need to be able to join with the second table, Employees. The query below seems simple enough but it's throwing back an error:

```
SELECT e.FirstName, e.LastName, e.Salary, jt.JobTitle, jt.JobDesc, jt.[Status]
From Employee e
JOIN Job_Title jt
ON e.EEO-1Class = jt.EEO-1Class
WHERE e.Salary BETWEEN 10000 AND 40000
```

It blows up on e.EEO-1Class saying "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'Class'.

The fields I'm joining are int fields already so I'm confused about what I'm missing. I'm sure this is one of those "duh" answers :)

Comment: is `EE0-1Class` a column? Surround it with brackets `[EE0-1Class]` or double-quotes `"EE0-1Class"` (What is your DBMS?). The minus character is parsed as the minus sign.

Comment: ouuuuh, your column names are... exotic. I guess your problems come from the "-" and numbers. I don't know what sql derivate you are using but try putting the columns in \`s (like \`e.EEO-1Class\` = ...) and try your luck again.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the name of the field into square brackets.

So change...

```
ON e.EEO-1Class = jt.EEO-1Class
```

Into

```
ON e.[EEO-1Class] = jt.[EEO-1Class]
```

If your field or table name contains just alphanumeric characters (ie A-Z and 0-9) and the underscore `_` character, then you can use it without square brackets (`[` and `]`).

But as soon as you have a different characters in there (and one that can easily be confused by SQL server, such as `-`) then you need to place the field/table into square brackets.

However, what I would recommend above everything else is that you only ever use alphanumeric characters (and the underscore `_` character) for your field and table names, as it is considered better practise, and will remove this type of thing happening again for you

Answer (score 2):

I think it may be the '-'  in the column names. Try putting it inside [] brackets.

Answer (score 2):

escape your column names: `EEO-1Class` and `EEO-1Class`  with brackets. The server performs *substraction* because of `-` sign.

```
SELECT e.FirstName, e.LastName, e.Salary, jt.JobTitle, jt.JobDesc, jt.[Status]
From Employee e
JOIN Job_Title jt
ON e.[EEO-1Class] = jt.[EEO-1Class]     -- << this two columns.
WHERE e.Salary BETWEEN 10000 AND 40000
```

Comment: See, I figured it would be a "Duh" moment. That make sense. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.